# Local webpage content type

Tags: html, content-type

I have a program that will download some web pages to view them offline. Those pages has the extension `.ASPX`. when I open the webpage in the browser it will show the page as XML but the page is actually HTML5 and has the document type `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Is there a way to tell the browser to treat it as HTML without changing the extension? Because the webpages has links that reference each other.

I tried to add to the page `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. That fixed the encoding problem that I had but the browser is still treating it as XML even though it says `text/html`.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. No idea what can be done, if anything. The only idea that comes to mind is an old-style HTML 4 doctype definition with a link to a DTD